# Blazor .NET C# can't get input from html <form>

Tags: c#, html, .net, razor, visual-studio-2022

When I try to get input from the user using the html `<form>` thing, I get the error:

> CS0103 Der Name "Request" ist im aktuellen Kontext nicht vorhanden.

This translates to

> CS0103 The name "Request" does not exist in the current context

This is my C# code:

```
@{
    double distance = 0;

    if (Request.Query.ContainsKey("distance"))
    {
        double.TryParse(Request.Query["distance"], out distance);
    }
```

My HTML markup:

```
<p>Enter distance:</p>
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="distance" />
    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Normally this should get the user input, but it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means compiler cannot find the class Request

To get text input :

```
    @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@{
    double distance = 0;

    var uri = NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(NavigationManager.Uri);
    var query = Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query);

    if (query.ContainsKey("distance"))
    {
        double.TryParse(query["distance"], out distance);
        Console.WriteLine(distance.ToString());
    }
}

<p>Enter distance:</p>
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="distance" />
    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```